# MomentJS - How to change locale but keep language

Tags: reactjs, datetime, momentjs, locale, lang

I'm using `react-datetime` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime to make a datetime picker for my app.
It's look like https://codepen.io/simeg/pen/yVVjdJ.

```
var date = new Date();
React.render(
  <div>
    <Datetime input={false} locale="fr-en" />
  </div>,
  document.body
);
```

And result is:
[image]
Now I wanna change my Datetime locale to another locale (ex: Fr, de or vi) but keep Eng is language of my datetime board.
How can? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [customizing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) the locale

[**Demo**](https://codepen.io/aswinkumar863/pen/mdbXdZw)

```
moment.locale('fr-ca', {
    months : 'January_February_March_April_May_June_July_August_September_October_November_December'.split('_'),
    monthsShort : 'Jan_Feb_Mar_Apr_May_Jun_Jul_Aug_Sep_Oct_Nov_Dec'.split('_'),
    weekdays : 'Sunday_Monday_Tuesday_Wednesday_Thursday_Friday_Saturday'.split('_'),
    weekdaysShort : 'Sun_Mon_Tue_Wed_Thu_Fri_Sat'.split('_'),
    weekdaysMin : 'Su_Mo_Tu_We_Th_Fr_Sa'.split('_')
});
```